# MongoDB query returning more than expected for nmap data

Tags: mongodb, nosql

Here's an excerpt of an nmap scan that I've converted from xml into json format:

```
{
    "nmaprun": {
        "@scanner": "nmap", 
        "@args": "nmap -T4 -F -sV -O -n --exclude 192.168.10.1 -oX nmap-00:90:a9:0e:87:21.xml 192.168.10.1/24", 
        "@start": "1470812419", 
        "@startstr": "Wed Aug 10 00:00:19 2016", 
        "@version": "7.12", 
        "@xmloutputversion": "1.04", 
        "scaninfo": {
            "@type": "syn", 
            "@protocol": "tcp", 
            "@numservices": "100", 
        "host": {
            "@starttime": "1470812419", 
            "@endtime": "1470812462", 
            "status": {
                "@state": "up", 
                "@reason": "arp-response", 
                "@reason_ttl": "0"
            }, 
            "address": [
                {
                    "@addr": "192.168.1.123", 
                    "@addrtype": "ipv4"
                }, 
                {
                    "@addr": "18:B4:30:4C:94:1B", 
                    "@addrtype": "mac"
                }
            ]
}
```

The return of the following query that attempts to look up and project the MAC address + address type has extra fields in it

```
db.nmaps.find({"nmaprun.host.address.@addr":"18:B4:30:4C:94:1B","nmaprun.host.address.@addrtype":"mac"},{"nmaprun.host.address.@addrtype":1, "nmaprun.host.address.@addr":1}).pretty()
```

Returns extra fields that do not match the  parameters of the query. Specifically, the ipv4 and ip address also get returned. Not sure why this is happening.

Return of query:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("57acb4c35e18500dc5f4d7d8"),
  "nmaprun" : {
    "host" : {
      "address" : [
        {
          "@addr" : "",
          "@addrtype" : "ipv4"
        },
        {
          "@addr" : "18:B4:30:4C:94:1B",
          "@addrtype" : "mac"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting both array elements is that the entire document is considered a match to the find criteria you've provided, and there is nothing in your projection to limit the results to only the matched array element.

A simple way to change what you have to get the expected results is to use the positional $ operator (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/) in your projection:

```
db.nmaps.find({"nmaprun.host.address.@addr":"18:B4:30:4C:94:1B","nmaprun.host.address.@addrtype":"mac"},{"nmaprun.host.address.$":1}).pretty()
```

Another way to do it would be using aggregation:

```
db.nmaps.aggregate([
    {
        $unwind: "$nmaprun.host.address"
    },
    {
        $match:{
            "nmaprun.host.address.@addr":"18:B4:30:4C:94:1B",
            "nmaprun.host.address.@addrtype":"mac"
        }
    },
    {
        $project:{
            "nmaprun.host.address.@addrtype":1, 
            "nmaprun.host.address.@addr":1
        }
    }
])
```